# mysql GROUP BY to display all corresponding fields

Tags: mysql

My table is as follows:

```
ID      EMP_ID      NAME        ACTIVITY_DATE       ACTIVITY_CODE

1       EMP01      ROCKY        2018-02-19          AC04  
2       EMP02      SMITH        2018-02-19          AC09
3       EMP02      SMITH        2018-02-19          AC10
4       EMP01      ROCKY        2018-02-20          AC04
5       EMP01      ROCKY        2018-02-20          AC04
6       EMP03      RICKY        2018-02-22          AC05
7       EMP03      RICKY        2018-02-22          AC07
8       EMP02      SMITH        2018-02-22          AC09
```

I want to eliminate duplicate dates from the query result and display all the corresponding fields order by ID and my table should be like:

```
ID      EMP_ID      NAME        ACTIVITY_DATE    ACTIVITY_CODE     COUNT

1       EMP01      ROCKY        2018-02-19          AC04            3
4       EMP01      ROCKY        2018-02-20          AC04            2
6       EMP03      RICKY        2018-02-22          AC05            3
```

I've tried this query:

```
SELECT ID, EMP_ID, NAME, ACTIVITY_DATE, ACTIVITY_CODE 
FROM emp_entries
GROUP BY ID, EMP_ID, NAME, ACTIVITY_DATE, ACTIVITY_CODE
```

But its not eliminating duplicate entries.

Its working only if i do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ACTIVITY_DATE), ACTIVITY_DATE 
FROM emp_entries
GROUP BY ACTIVITY_DATE.
```

but it shows only one field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use inner join and subquery:

select e1.ID ,e1.EMP_ID ,e1.NAME,e1.ACTIVITY_DATE,e1.ACTIVITY_CODE,e2.count 
from emp_entries e1 inner join
(
SELECT COUNT(ACTIVITY_DATE) as count, ACTIVITY_DATE, min(id) as mid
FROM emp_entries
GROUP BY ACTIVITY_DATE
) e2 on e1.id=e2.mid
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland, group by is inside in a subquery - SELECT COUNT(ACTIVITY_DATE) as count, ACTIVITY_DATE, min(id) as mid
FROM emp_entries
GROUP BY ACTIVITY_DATE

Comment: Never mind.. i read it wrong because of the formatting.. Geuss i need some coffee to wake up.

Comment: It's ok, @RaymondNijland..it's bit clumsy I saw :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subquery` and `join` to do it

```
   SELECT e1.id,e1.EMP_ID,e1.NAME,e1.ACTIVITY_DATE ,e1.ACTIVITY_CODE,e2.cnt 
    FROM emp_entries e1
    JOIN(
        SELECT COUNT(ACTIVITY_DATE) as cnt,MIN(id) AS mId
        FROM emp_entries
        GROUP BY ACTIVITY_DATE) e2 
    ON e2.mId=e1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Distinct keyword to eliminate duplicates.

Select Distinct col1, col 2 etc

Answer (score 0):

As you are grouping by that table, you must use group functions, in your example I can see that you show the first element, so, I think this query will work for you.

```
SELECT 
    MIN(ID) as ID,
    MIN(EMP_ID) as EMP_ID,
    MIN(NAME) as NAME,
    ACTIVITY_DATE, 
    MIN(ACTIVITY_CODE) as ACTIVITY_CODE,
    COUNT(ID) as COUNT
FROM emp_entries
GROUP BY ACTIVITY_DATE
```